# Moveit interactive marker missing on new kinetic version

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using Moveit totally fine on ROS Kinetic (version: 1.12.7). However, after I upgraded to the newer version (1.12.12). the interactive markers just disappear. Anyone has the same problem or know how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278820/moveit-interactive-marker-missing-on-new-kinetic-version/) by [Quang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33150/quang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known regression in RViz, not in MoveIt.

Please see [ros-planning/moveit#736](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/736) and [ros-visualization/rviz#1179](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1179).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Quang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33150/quang/) on 2018-01-07**:
Great, thanks for your reply.

**Comment by [七小丘人](https://answers.ros.org/users/33153/%E4%B8%83%E5%B0%8F%E4%B8%98%E4%BA%BA/) on 2018-01-10**:
请问这个补丁去哪下？怎么装？

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-11**:
Please only use English on this forum.